# should not load tabbar item based on permission ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am trying to load a tabbar with multiple view, but I want few tabs opened only if the user has permission. Is there any delegate call that will handle this? I looked in tabbardelegate it only has didSelectItem unlike the textfield which has bool for return text so I choice to return or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item` you discussed.

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    if (item == 2 || item == 3) { //Tab 2 and 3 are protected
        if (!userHasPermission) {
            tabBar.selectedItem = 0; //Make user go to first tab if the user does not have permission.
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you want certain items disabled.  In your `-viewDidLoad`

```
if (!userHasPermission) {
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = [[myTabBar items] objectAtIndex:2];
    [tabBarItem setEnabled:NO];
}
```

Comment: Is this the only solution? Because in my case I have to always remember the previous tab.

Comment: You can disable items that you don't want to be able to click.  Answer edited.

Comment: That sound good solution. Thanks. 1 last question, I am using a tabbarcontroller not tabbar . I don't find didSelectItem call in tabbarcontroller delegate. So I make tabbarCOntroller.tabbar.delegate = self I get this error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Changing the delegate of a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.'

Comment: Ahh, should have said so.  Then you want to me the TabBarController's Delegate, not the TabBar's.  Then you have access to `- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController`

Comment: How do I get the index of the selected item I am only getting view controller? I tried using is kind of class but it did not work. Any idea?

Comment: I figured it out. I was adding my view to navigation bar.